# time(NULL) in c++ only counts seconds, not milliseconds

Tags: c++, time

I'm not sure whether what this is true or not, but in my code, I'm printing the value of a variable called currentTime which records the number of seconds since the application was run. The currentTime variable is recorded as 
    time(NULL) - epocTime
where epocTime was set to time(NULL) at the beggining of the code.
even though currentTime is of type double, it prints out as 1.0000, 2.0000, 3.0000, and so on as my application runs. However it never has a non integer value. Is it possible for me to change how I record time, so that the milliseconds are also recorded, for example is there a parameter I can give the time() method to make it record milliseconds.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono

Comment: `time()` gives you integers. It doesn't matter what you assign and convert that value to. It cannot magically obtain microseconds resolution.

Answer (score 1):

`time()` almost always returns an integral type that contains the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970. There's not much you can do with `time()` itself to change that.

Instead you should look into [`std::chrono::steady_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    // Some work
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = end - start;

    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(elapsed).count() << " milliseconds\n";
}
```

Comment: _"Not much"_ Or, in fact, nothing. And [your `std::clock` suggestion is simply wrong](http://kera.name/articles/2011/03/tomalaks-tuesday-tip-11-sleep-your-way-to-success/).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I always forget which of the older clocks return wall time or cpu time and if they fail miserably when your process switches processes. So let's just delete that part of the answer. Thank you the for the link though, and I may beat that into my memory one of these days.